# Have we given up on the idea of code reuse?

Tags: components, soa, code-reuse

A couple of years ago the media was rife with all sorts of articles on
how the idea of code reuse was a simple way to improve productivity
and code quality.

From the blogs and sites I check on a regular basis it seems as though
the idea of "code reuse" has gone out of fashion. Perhaps the 'code
reuse' advocates have all joined the SOA crowd instead? :-)

Interestingly enough, when you search for 'code reuse' in Google the
second result is titled:

"Internal Code Reuse Considered Dangerous"!

To me the idea of code reuse is just common sense, after all look at
the success of the apache commons project!

What I want to know is:

- Do you or your company try and reuse code?
- If so how and at what level, i.e. low level api, components or
  shared business logic? How do you or your company reuse code?
- Does it work?

Discuss?

---

I am fully aware that there are many open source libs available and that anyone who has used .NET or the Java has reused code in some form. That is common sense!

I was referring more to code reuse within an organizations rather than across a community via a shared lib etc.

I originally asked;

- Do you or your company try and reuse code?
- If so how and at what level, i.e. low level api, components or shared business logic? How do you or your company reuse code?

From where I sit I see very few example of companies trying to reuse code internally?

If you have a piece of code which could potentially be shared across a medium size organization how would you go about informing other members of the company that this lib/api/etc existed and could be of benefit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The title of the article you are referring to is misleading, and is actually a very good read.  Code reuse is very beneficial, but there are downsides with everything.  Basically, if I remember correctly, the gist of the article is that you are sealing the code in a black box and not revisiting it, so as the original developers leave you lose the knowledge.  While I see the point, I don't necessarily agree with it - at least not to a "sky is falling" regard.

We actually group code reuse into more than just reusable classes, we look at the entire enterprise.  Things that are more like framework enhancement or address cross-cutting concerns are put into a development framework that all of our applications use (think things like pre- and post-validation, logging, etc.).  We also have business logic that is applicable to more than one application, so those sort of things get moved to a BAL core that is accessible anywhere.

I think that the important thing is not to promote things for reuse if they are not going to really be reused.  They should be well documented, so that new developers can have a resource to help them come up to speed, as well.  Chances are, if the knowledge isn't shared, the code will eventually be reinvented somewhere else and will lead to duplication if you are not rigorous in documentation and knowledge sharing.

Comment: "The title of the article you are referring to..." I was not referring to anything in particular, did this ring a bell with something you have read before? Karl

Comment: The second result you saw in Google.  "Internal Code Reuse Considered Dangerous".  It is a whitepaper that I read a while back.

Comment: For anyone interested, here's an Internet Archive [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20060114092919id_/http://www.yafla.com/dennisforbes/Internal-Code-Reuse-Considered-Dangerous/Internal-Code-Reuse-Considered-Dangerous.html) to the (relatively short) referenced article (I think).

Answer (score 5):

We reuse code - in fact, our developers specifically write code that can be reused in other projects.  This has paid off quite nicely - we're able to start new projects quickly, and we iteratively harden our core libraries.

But one can't just write code and expect it to be re-used; **code reuse requires communication among team members** and other users so people know what code is available, and how to use it.

The following things are needed for code reuse to work effectively:

- The code or library itself
- Demand for the code across multiple projects or efforts
- Communication of the code's features/capabilities
- Instructions on how to use the code
- A commitment to maintaining and improving the code over time

Answer (score 3):

Code reuse is essential.  I find that it also forces me to generalize as much as possible, also making code more adaptable to varying situations.  Ideally, almost every lower level library you write should be able to adapt to a new set of requirements for a different application.

Comment: ".. every lower level library you write should be able to adapt to a new set of requirements for a different application" Say for example you write a low level JMS lib and you want to share it with the community, how would you go about sharing it? Its unlikely ill find it on your personal website.

Comment: There are many websites, applications and services available for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think code reuse is being done through open source projects for the most part.  Anything that can be reused or extended is being done via libraries.  Java has an amazing number of open source libraries available for doing a large number of things. Compare that to C++, and how early on everything would have to be implemented from scratch using MFC or the Win32 API.

Answer (score 1):

We reuse code.

On a small scale we try to avoid code duplication as much as posible. And we have a complete library with a lot of frequently used code.

Normally code is developed for one application. And if it is generic enough, it is promoted to the library. This works excelent.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of code reuse is no longer a novel idea...hence the apparent lack of interest. But it is still very much a good idea. The entire .NET framework and the Java API are good examples of code reuse in action.

We have grown accustomed to developing OO libraries of code for our projects and reusing them in other projects. Its a part of the natural life cycle of an idea. It is hotly debated for a while and then everyone accepts and there is no reason for further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Of course we reuse code.

There are a near infinite amount of packages, libraries and shared objects available for all languages, with whole communities of developers behing them supporting and updating.

Answer (score 1):

I think the lack of "media attention" is due to the fact that everyone is doing it, so it's no longer worth writing about.  I don't hear as many people raising awareness of Object-Oriented Programming and Unit Testing as I used to either.  Everyone is already aware of these concepts (whether they use them or not).

Answer (score 1):

Level of media attention to an issue has little to do with its importance, whether we're talking software development or politics! It's important to avoid wasting development effort by reinventing (or re-maintaining!) the wheel, but this is so well-known by now that an editor probably isn't going to get excited by another article on the subject.

Rather than looking at the number of current articles and blog posts as a measure of importance (or urgency) look at the concepts and buzz-phrases that have become classics or entered the jargon (another form of reuse!) For example, Google for uses of the DRY acronym for good discussion on the many forms of redundancy that can be eliminated in software and development processes.

There's also a role for mature judgment regarding costs of reuse vs. where the benefits are achieved. Some writers advocate waiting to worry about reuse until a second or third use actually emerges, rather than spending effort to generalize bit of code the first time it is written.

Answer (score 1):

My personal view, based on the practise in my company:

> - Do you or your company try and reuse code?

Obviously, if we have another piece of code that already fits our needs we will reuse it.  We don't go out of our way to use square pegs in round holes though.

> - If so how and at what level, i.e. low level api, components or shared business logic? How do you or your company reuse code?

At every level. It is written into our coding standards that developers should always assume their code will be reused - even if in reality that is highly unlikely. *See below*

If your OO model is good, your API probably reflects your business domain, so reusable classes probably equates to reusable business logic without additional effort.

For actual reuse, one key point is knowing what code is already available. We resolve this by having everything documented in a central location.  We just need a little discipline to ensure that the documentation is up-to-date and searchable in a meaningful way.

> - Does it work?

Yes, but not because of the potential or actual reuse! In reality, beyond a few core libraries and UI components, there isn't a large amount of reuse.

In my personal opinion, **the real value is in making the code reusable**.  In doing so, aside from a hopefully cleaner API, the code will (a) be documented sufficiently for another developer to use it *without trawling the source code*, and (b) it will also be *replaceable*.  These points are a great benefit to on-going software maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you or your company try and reuse code? If so how and at what
>   level, i.e. low level api, components or shared business logic? How do
>   you or your company reuse code?

I used to work in a codebase with uber code reuse, but it was difficult to maintain because the reused code was unstable. It was prone to design changes and deprecation in ways that cascaded to everything using it. Before that I worked in a codebase with no code reuse where the seniors actually encouraged copying and pasting as a way to reuse even application-specific code, so I got to see the two extremities and I have to say that one isn't necessarily much better than the other when taken to the extremes.

And I used to be an uber bottom-up kind of programmer. You ask me to build something specific and I end up building generalized tools. Then using those tools, I build more complex generalized tools, then start building DIP abstractions to express the design requirements for the lower-level tools, then I build even more complex tools and repeat, and at some point I start writing code that actually does what you want me to do. And as counter-productive as that sounded, I was pretty fast at it and could ship complex products in ways that really surprised people.

Problem was the maintenance over the months, years! After I built layers and layers of these generalized libraries and reused the hell out of them, each one wanted to serve a much greater purpose than what you asked me to do. Each layer wanted to solve the world's hunger needs. So each one was very ambitious: a math library that wants to be amazing and solve the world's hunger needs. Then something built on top of the math library like a geometry library that wants to be amazing and solve the world's hunger needs. You know something's wrong when you're trying to ship a product but your mind is mulling over how well your uber-generalized geometry library works for rendering and modeling when you're supposed to be working on animation because the animation code you're working on needs a few new geometry functions.

**Balancing Everyone's Needs**

I found in designing these uber-generalized libraries that I had to become obsessed with the needs of every single team member, and I had to learn how raytracing worked, how fluids dynamics worked, how the mesh engine worked, how inverse kinematics worked, how character animation worked, etc. etc. etc. I had to learn how to do pretty much everyone's job on the team because I was balancing all of their specific needs in the design of these uber generalized libraries I left behind while walking a tightrope balancing act of design compromises from all the code reuse (trying to make things better for Bob working on raytracing who is using one of the libraries but without hurting John too much who is working on physics who is also using it but without complicating the design of the library too much to make them both happy).

It got to a point where I was trying to parametrize bounding boxes with policy classes so that they could be stored either as center and half-size as one person wanted or min/max extents as someone else wanted, and the implementation was getting convoluted really fast trying to frantically keep up with everyone's needs.

**Design By Committee**

And because each layer was trying to serve such a wide range of needs (much wider than we actually needed), they found many reasons to require design changes, sometimes by committee-requested designs (which are usually kind of gross). And then those design changes would cascade upwards and affect all the higher-level code using it, and maintenance of such code started to become a real PITA.

I think you can potentially share more code in a like-minded team. Ours wasn't like-minded at all. These are not real names but I'd have Bill here who is a high-level GUI programmer and scripter who creates nice user-end designs but questionable code with lots of hacks, but it tends to be okay for that type of code. I got Bob here who is an old timer who has been programming since the punch card era who likes to write 10,000 line functions with gotos in them and still doesn't get the point of object-oriented programming. I got Joe here who is like a mathematical wizard but writes code no one else can understand and always make suggestions which are mathematically aligned but not necessarily so efficient from a computational standpoint. Then I got Mike here who is in outer space who wants us to port the software to iPhones and thinks we should all follow Apple's conventions and engineering standards.

Trying to satisfy everyone's needs here while coming up with a decent design was, probably in retrospect, impossible. And in everyone trying to share each other's code, I think we became counter-productive. Each person was competent in an area but trying to come up with designs and standards which everyone is happy with just lead to all kinds of instability and slowed everyone down.

**Trade-Offs**

So these days I've found the balance is to avoid code reuse for the lowest-level things. I use a top-down approach from the mid-level, perhaps (something not *too* far divorced from what you asked me to do), and build some independent library there which I can still do in a short amount of time, but the library doesn't intend to produce mini-libs that try to solve the world's hunger needs. Usually such libraries are a little more narrow in purpose than the lower-level ones (ex: a physics library as opposed to a generalized geometry-intersection library).

YMMV, but if there's anything I've learned over the years in the hardest ways possible, it's that there might be a balancing act and a point where we might want to deliberately avoid code reuse in a team setting at some granular level, abandoning some generality for the lowest-level code in favor of decoupling, having malleable code we can better shape to serve more specific rather than generalized needs, and so forth -- maybe even just letting everyone have a little more freedom to do things their own way. But of course all of this is with the aim of still producing a very reusable, generalized library, but the difference is that the library might not decompose into the teeniest generalized libraries, because I found that crossing a certain threshold and trying to make too many teeny, generalized libraries starts to actually become an extremely counter-productive endeavor in the long term -- not in the short term, but in the long run and broad scheme of things.

> If you have a piece of code which could potentially be shared across a
>   medium size organization how would you go about informing other
>   members of the company that this lib/api/etc existed and could be of
>   benefit?

I actually am more reluctant these days and find it more forgivable if colleagues do some redundant work because I would want to make sure that code does something fairly useful and non-trivial and is also really well-tested and designed before I try to share it with people and accumulate a bunch of dependencies to it. The design should have very, very few reasons to require any changes from that point onwards if I share it with the rest of the team.

Otherwise it could cause more grief than it actually saves.

I used to be so intolerant of redundancy (in code or efforts) because it appeared to translate to a product that was very buggy and explosive in memory use. But I zoomed in too much on redundancy as the key problem, when really the real problem was poor quality, hastily-written code, and a lack of solid testing. Well-tested, reliable, efficient code wouldn't suffer that problem to nearly as great of a degree even if some people duplicate, say, some math functions here and there.

One of the common sense things to look at and remember that I didn't at the time is how we don't mind some redundancy when we use a very solid third party library. Chances are that you guys use a third party library or two that has some redundant work with what your team is doing. But we don't mind in those cases because the third party library is great and well-tested. I recommend applying that same mindset to your own internal code. The goal should be to create something awesome and well-tested, not to fuss over a little bit of redundancy here and there as I mistakenly did long ago.

So these days I've shifted my intolerance towards a lack of testing instead. Instead of getting upset over redundant efforts, I find it much more productive to get upset over other people's lack of unit and integration testing! :-D

Answer (score 0):

While I think code reuse is valuable, I can see where this sentiment is rooted. I've worked on a lot of projects where much extra care was taken to create re-usable code that was then never reused. Of course reuse is much preferable to duplicate code, but I have seen a lot of very extenisve object models created with the goal of using the objects across the enterprise in multiple projects (kind of the way the same service in SOA can be used in different apps) but have never seen the objects actually used more than once. Maybe I just haven't been part of organizations taking good advantage of the principle of reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the better question is when do we NOT reuse code these days? We are either in a state on building using someone elses observed "best practices" or prediscovered "design patterns" or just actually building on legacy code, libraries, or copying.

It seems the degree to which code A is reused to make code B is often based around how much the ideas in code A taken to code B are abstracted into design patterns/idioms/books/fleeting thoughts/actual code/libraries. The hard part is in applying all those good ideas to your actual code.

Non-technical types get overzealous about the reuse thing. They don't understand why everything can't be copy-pasted. They don't understand why the greemelfarm needs a special adapter to communicate the same information that it used to to the old system to the new system, and that, unfortunately we can't change either due to a bazillion other reasons.

I think techies have been reusing from day 1 in the same way musicians have been reusing from day 1. Its an ongoing organic evolution and sythesis that will keep ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

The two software projects I've worked on have both been long term development.  One is about 10 years old, the other has been around for over 30 years, rewritten in a couple versions of Fortran along the way.  Both make extensive reuse of code, but both rely very little on external tools or code libraries.  DRY is a big mantra on the newer project, which is in C++ and lends itself more easily to doing that in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Code reuse is an extremely important issue - where code is not reused, projects take longer and are harder for new team members to get into.
However, writing reusable code takes longer.

Personally, I try to write all my code in a reusable way, this takes longer, but it results in the fact that most of my code has become official infrastructures in my organization and that new projects based on these infrastructures take significantly less time.

The danger in reusing code, is if the reused code is not written as an infrastructure - in a general and encapsulated manner with as few as possible assumptions and as much as possible documentation and unit testing, that the code can end up doing unexpected things.
Also, if bugs are found and fixed, or features added, these changes are rarely returned to the source code, resulting in different versions of the reused code, that no one knows of or understands.

The solution is:
1. To design and write the code with not only one project in mind, but to think of future requirements and try to make the design flexible enough to cover them with minimal code change.
2. To enclose the code within libraries that are to be used as-is and not modified within using projects.
3. To allow users to view and modify the code of of the library withing ***its*** solution (not within the using project's solution).
4. To design future projects to be based on the existing infrastructures, making changes to the infrastructures as necessary.
5. To charge maintaining the infrastructure to all projects, thus keeping the infrastructure funded.

Answer (score -1):

Maven has solved code reuse. I'm completely serious.

Comment: Maven makes it quite easy to describe dependencies between software elements, but you still have to be aware of code duplication in the things you write.